# Remote postgres database disconnects frequently on azure

Tags: postgresql, azure, remote-server, datagrip, database-connectivity

I have installed Postgres(11) on Azure, I am connecting to it using Datagrip client, The problem is it disconnects very frequently and connects back when I run some query, takes nearly 5 seconds to connect back. Here I am attaching a picture of [AdvancedSettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UarsP.png) which I have tried already
but this doesn't seem to work, can you please suggest a solution so this stays connected for more than 10 mins at least.

Comment: Why don't you stay connected?

Comment: I want to be connected all the time, but during my development, If I read some document or due to any reason if I stop using the DB Client for 5 mins it gets disconnected, when I run some query it starts connecting again, synchronizing, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution depends on who closes the connection.

- If the connection is closed by the benighted Azure configuration, [configure DataGrip so that it sends keepalive packets](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/configuring-database-connections.html#keep-the-connection-alive):

  > On the **Options** tab, select the **Run keep-alive query each N seconds** checkbox, where `N` is a number of seconds after which DataGrip runs a keep-alive query again.
- If the connection is closed by DataGrip, [tell it not to do that](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/configuring-database-connections.html#disconnect-from-a-database-in-a-specified-period):

  On the Options tab, **de**select the **Auto-disconnect after N seconds** checkbox.